# Check the availability of a resource before applying to a project task VBA MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am using VBA to assign Resources (Rooms) to tasks in MS Project based on where the session is being held, the room capacity and Room availability.  I am stuck on the room availability part.  I assume there must be some way to hook into the availability properties of the Resource object to quickly determine if the Resource has been applied to another task already.

Cheers

```
Sub Allocate_Rooms()
'Allocating a Resource (Room) to a Task based on the location of the 
facility, room capacity and availability
Dim T As Task
Dim R As Resource

For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks
i = 0

If Left(T.Name, 1) <> "M" Then 'Checks to see if the task is a valid Module session
    GoTo SkipT
End If

For Each R In ActiveProject.Resources
    If Left(R.Name, 2) <> "R-" Then 'Skips resources that are not rooms
        GoTo SkipR
    End If

    If T.Text5 = R.Text3 Then 'The Resource (Room) is in the same facility as the sesssion that is being held
        If T.Text1 <= R.Text1 Then 'Check the number of users is less than or equal to the Room Capacity
            'If ??????
                'Something in here to check the availability of the Resource (Room).  This would be based on the set calendar
                'of the Resource and also would check if the room has been allocated to another Task in the Project

                T.ResourceNames = R.Name 'Assign the resource to the task

            Goto SkipT
             'End if
        End If
    End If

SkipR:
Next R 'next Resource
SkipT:

Next T 'Next Task

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [TimeScaleData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.resource.timescaledata) method of the Resource object to return a [TimeScaleValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.timescalevalues) object that can be used to determine the amount of work already assigned to that resource for a given time period (e.g. the duration of the task). For example:

```
Dim tsvs As TimeScaleValues
Set tsvs = R.TimeScaleData(T.Start, T.Finish, pjResourceTimescaledWork, pjTimescaleYears)
If tsvs(1).Value = 0 Then
    T.ResourceNames = R.Name
    ' exit loop now that room is assigned
End If
```

Note that the unit used here is `pjTimescaleYears` so that the entire work for the resource during the period of the task is lumped into one value (unless the task spans more than one year). If you were to use the default `pjTimescaleDays` and the task spanned more than one day, `tsvs` would have more than one element that would need to be checked.

Comment: That is great!  Thank you!  I actually went with the 'pjTimescaleHours' options as I am looking at scheduling sessions that are less than a day

Comment: If your tasks are longer than an hour and you need to be sure the room isn’t already assigned for any part of that time, using a larger unit makes the job much easier. Otherwise for a task that runs more than an hour you will need to loop through all elements of the ‘tsvs’ array to check each one. Using the Years unit will automatically give you the sum of hours the room is assigned **just for the span of the task** since you provide the task start/finish dates; in other words using the Year unit does not mean you are getting a year’s worth of data.